# Unable to load class named 'MyLocations.Location' for entity 'Location'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

When I created my core data file and after adding this code into done method to save the data I got an error of above stated topic of unable to find a class.

It also showing an error of

> Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead

```
@IBAction func done()
{
    let hudView = HudView.hudInView(navigationController!.view, animated: true)

    hudView.text = "Tagged"

    let location = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Location

    location.locationDescription = descriptionText

    location.category = categoryName

    location.latitude = coordinate.latitude

    location.longitude = coordinate.longitude

    location.date = date

    location.placemark = placemark

    var error: NSError?

    if !managedObjectContext.save(&error)
    {
        println("Error: \(error)")

        abort()
    }

    afterDelay(0.6) {self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}
}
```

Comment: Do you have Location class in your project directory?

Comment: yes i have but location file not a location class

Comment: i have location class also in project in my project directory

Comment: Is it " class Location: NSManagedObject { " something like this?

Comment: Yes same as you said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87128/discussion-between-karlos-and-shahin-ali-agharia).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the class in your xcdatamodeld file.
Go to your projectname.xcdatamodeld -> select the Location table and then select the Data model inspector as show in screenshot below and set the class.

[image]

Hope this might be helpful.

Make the following changes in your code

```
 var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
 var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel11.managedObjectContext!
 var location = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
```

Comment: Getting the same error. But I already did this before and it doesn't works.

Comment: Can you drag the Location file and add it project main directory and try it again?